# PHP - скрипт который заполняет и отправляет форму

Tags: php, форма

Возникла задача написать скрипт, который заполняет форму (логин и пароль) в уже существующем сайте, и вывести на экран сообщение которое выводится в случае успешной авторизации.

Скажите пожалуйста, в каком направлении стоит начать делать это задание, что гуглить, и какие библиотеки для этого есть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=curl+%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1):

существующий сайт - это сторонний или тот, к коду которого у вас есть доступ? в первом случае нужно отправлять `http` запрос, во втором не совсем понятно, зачем это. у вас форма передает данные скрипту, идите в этот скрипт, установите там в начале логин и пароль. или используйте `js`, чтобы заполнить поля и засабмитить форму